# Netbeans code templates with changing value

Tags: templates, netbeans, ide

Is it possible to create code template that will use written value?

simple example:

firstly: `while + tab` gives standard while code.

I would like to create something where `while 100 + tab` would give:

```
while (i<100) {

}
```

Where 100 is given value and can be different. Also would be nice to have more than one custom value.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools -> Options`.

Then click on `Editor` and go to `Code Templates` tab.

Click `New`, give and abbreviation and the code template.

Look at the existing templates, like `whilexp` - it shows how
to prompt for input on the code template.